# Apply Lambda Last Character If Statement

Tags: python

half of my records have a @ at the end and half do not.. I'd like to standardize things by creating an IF it has it, THEN leave alone, ELSE add it.

```
turbo['user'] = turbo['user'].apply(lambda x: x if x[-1] == '@' else str(x) + '@')
```

But I'm receiving an error:

> IndexError: string index out of range -

what would be driving this? I believe there are no blanks

Comment: That explicitly means some strings are empty

Comment: As you do `x[-1]` I assume the column only contains string, so no need of `str()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.endswith` instead, which can work with an empty string.

```
turbo['user'] = turbo['user'].apply(lambda x: x if x.endswith('@') else x + '@')
```

Comment: You can save a little space with `lambda x: x + '@' * (not x.endswith('@'))` taking advantage of `str * bool`

Comment: That's starting to look more like Perl than any sane expression :)

Comment: I toyed with `lambda x: x.rstrip('@') + '@'`, which removes *all* trailing `@` (if any), then appends exactly 1. Aside from assuming that no string will end with more than one `@`, though, there's the cost of calling `rstrip` when unnecessary (effectively making a copy of the string).

Comment: (`x.rstrip('@', 1)` would be nice, if supported, but there's still the overhead of an unnecessary method call.)

Comment: @flakes:  I suspect this is somewhat less efficient.  Python has to call the concatenation method for every string, even though many of the concatenations will be of the empty string.    And I also don't know if the string "multiply" routine has a fastpath for 0 and 1.

Comment: I forgot about `x.removesuffix('@') + '@'`. Looks nice, but still more expensive than a no-op for strings already ending in `'@'`.

Answer (score 1):

As you use `x[-1]`, I'll assume the column contains string, so don't need of `str()` wrapping

---

You could add a second condition `if x`, to check for non empty string

```
lambda x: x if x and x[-1] == '@' else x + "@"
```

But better just use

```
lambda x: x if x.endswidth("@") else x + "@"
```